# Angular6 chartjs-plugin-streaming onRefresh() not working

Tags: angular6, ionic4, chartjs-2.6.0

I got some problem to plot a graph in "real time" with chartjs.

**The context is as follows:**
I receive data live via a connection to websocket. The frequency is about every 200ms. the idea is then to be able to display these data on graph in "real time".

For that I decided to use chartjs with a plugin called [chartjs-streaming](https://github.com/nagix/chartjs-plugin-streaming) that I can use with Angular.

**Problem:**
By following this [sample](https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-streaming/) (version angular2 +) I manage to display the empty graph, but the function onRefresh () does not execute so that my graph is always empty ...

**My component html**

```
<div style="display: block">
  <canvas baseChart [chartType]="'line'" [datasets]="datasets" [options]="options">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

**My component ts**

```
  ...
  import 'chartjs-plugin-streaming';
  ...
  datasets: any[] = [{ data: [] }, { data: [] }];
  options: any = {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{ type: 'time' }]
    },
    plugins: {
      streaming: {
        onRefresh: function (chart: any) {
          alert("REFRESH");
          console.log("test");
          chart.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset: any) {
            dataset.data.push({
              x: Date.now(),
              y: Math.random()
            });
          });
        },
      }
    }
```

**Package.json**

```
"@types/chart.js": "^2.7.42",
"angular-chart.js": "^1.1.1",
"chart.js": "^2.7.3",
"chartjs-plugin-streaming": "^1.7.1",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

In my environment, this code worked if `xAxes: [{ type: 'time' }]` was replaced with `xAxes: [{ type: 'realtime' }]`